# sending input to a program called by the "at command"

Tags: linux, bash, at-job

I have a program which accepts 2 prompts (y/n). For example:

stopprogram

```
do you want to stop the program (Y/N)? y
do you want to send an email to the admin about it (Y/N)? y
```

Now, I'd like to automate that using the 'at' command. the following works on Solaris but not on Linux RHEL:

```
at now +5 minutes << EOF
 > for i in {1..2}
 > do
 > echo 'y'
 > done | stopprogram
 > EOF
commands will be executed using /usr/bin/bash
...
...
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: you say automate running your program, but `at` requires a cmd-line and that you press the enter key to start the program. Do you know about `crontab`? using the `cron` sub-systems allows complete hands-off launching of programs. Also, you need to improve  your Q and tell us what happens in RH; nothing at all? or hopefully you get an error message? Copy/paste the exact error msg into your Q (and use the `{}` tool on the edit tool on that highlighted text to keep it properly formatted). Finally, guessing that `at` does work in RH, but that  you're encountering a permissions problem. Good luck.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem
statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your
question to give a more complete description of what you
expected to happen and how that differs from the actual
results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good
explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be because of the space between `<<` and `EOF`.

Note that there is a special program `yes` for repeatedly outputting a line composed of all of its arguments. By default it outputs 'y'. It was created specially for forcing a scripted flow through those prompts.

Thus the short version of your command will look like this:

```
at now +5 minutes <<EOF
   yes | stopprogram
EOF
```

Comment: Here documents are treated as double quotes strings, unless `<<'EOF'` is used in which case it's treated as single quotes string. (See the single quotes around the marker?)

Comment: No luck.  If I just type: "yes | stopprogram" it works.  But can't get it properly using the 'at' command

Comment: What kind of a problem do you run into?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  This will work:

```
at now+5 min <<EOF
bash -l -c 'yes | stopprogram'
EOF
```

That's it!